# The magnetic force is conservative when the magnetic field is static, what is its potential function then?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields, potential-energy, conservative-field

The magnetic force $\vec{F}$ can be conservative when the magnetic field is a static. That is $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F}=0$, so it follows that there is a scalar function $f$ such that $\vec{F}=q \vec{v} \times \vec{B}=\vec{\nabla}f$, how can I get this function $f$?

Comment: Related [Magnetic Scalar Potential](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_scalar_potential)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This result that:
$$
F = -\nabla U
$$
if $F$ is a conservative forces:
$$
\oint F\cdot dx = 0
$$
only works when they only have a spatial dependence. It does not apply to the magnetic force which also has a velocity dependence. Indeed, the magnetic force never works, so by the usual method of saying that $U$ is the potential energy, i.e. the work to a reference point, this would mean that $U=cst$.

The idea is that you need to generalise the notion to the case where $U$ has a velocity dependence as well. You'll therefore need to adapt the gradient to take into account velocity as well. The usual approach is to use Lagrangian mechanics, so that your $U=-qv\cdot A$ with $A$ the potential vector:
$$
B = \nabla\times A
$$
$U$ is related to $F$ by the Euler-Lagrange equations:
$$
F = \left(\frac{d}{dt}\nabla_v-\nabla_x\right)U
$$

Hope this helps.